# update one value in JsonStore

Tags: extjs

How to update particular value in Jsone store dynamically?
When adding one new record to store, based on new record, update existing records in store

Answer (score 1):

it depends you want to update existing record before adding new records to store or after adding new records to store. for updating after adding new records to store you can do something like:

```
store.on('add', function(store, newRecordsArray, indexWhereRecordsAdded ){
    /* handle update here */
});
store.loadData( newDataArray, true /* to append data */ );
```

for updating before adding new records to store just do it before passing data to loadData